# underscore-contrib can't use the _.snapshot function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using the underscore.js library (version 1.8.3) on my project, on one of the scripts I needed to deep clone an object, because the _.clone(obj) function only does a shallow clone, I've added the underscore-contrib (version 0.3.0) library I grabbed from the source repo

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-contrib.min.js"></script>
```

and attempted to use the _.snapshot(obj) function like so

```
var clonedData = _.clone(data); // works 
var snapshotData = _.snapshot(data); // doesn't work
```

It didn't work, the console shows

```
TypeError: _.snapshot is not a function
```

Eventually I tried to "hack it", I've copy pasted the function contents from the development version into a function in my script and it worked fine, but It's kind of ugly, I want to avoid the duplication and use it properly. what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the specific underscore-contrib library - in your case that's `object.builders` - in your example:

```js
var data = {x:3,y:{z:5}};
var snapshotData = _.snapshot(data); // doesn't work

data.y.z = 3;
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snapshotData);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/documentcloud/underscore-contrib/master/underscore.object.builders.js"></script>
```

Personally - I'd use lodash which already has a `_.cloneDeep` method and is already modular and faster.